# Scala: Map list elements to a function of another list elements

Tags: scala

I am very new to scala, I am trying to map the values of a list to the values obtained by running a function on the values of another list

What I mean is that I have an list A and another B. There is a function say func(b) which takes input as an element of the list B.

If I were to map it to list elements to a function of its own elements I could do it like this

```
val evalData = A.map(a=>(a, func(a)))
```

But I can't understand how to do it for my use case. Can someone please help me !! Thanks !

Comment: Can you give an example input and what the example output would be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suspect from your question that list A and B have the same length.
For example, you could have:

```
val listA = List(1,2)
val listB = List(3,4)
def f(a:Int) = a+1
val result = listA zip (listB map f)
result: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,4), (2,5))
```

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for !!